# Reflection Parameter count mismatch when using thread to update Windows Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Need help with a simple scenario: I want to update label text to track progress in a Windows Form.

I successfully used Invoke method with delegate (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8))

But I want to display text that varies - so I want to pass different text from various methods. I made changes to the example in that link so it's like what's below, but then I get this exception in DynamicInvokeImpl:

System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Parameter count mismatch.'

Calls from multiple other methods...

```
thread2 = new Thread(() => SetText("Doing Stuff", mytextvarItem));
thread2.Start();
```

The sample code:

```
private delegate void SafeCallDelegate(string State, string Item);

    public void SetText(string State, string Item)
    {
       WriteTextSafe(State, Item);
    }

private void WriteTextSafe(string State, string Item)
            if (lblState.InvokeRequired)
            {
                var d = new SafeCallDelegate(WriteTextSafe);
                lblState.Invoke(d, new object[] { State });
            }
            else
            {
                lblState.Text = State;
            }

            if (lblItem.InvokeRequired)
            {
                var d = new SafeCallDelegate(WriteTextSafe);
                lblItem.Invoke(d, new object[] { Item});
            }
            else
            {
                lblItem.Text = Item;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove everything and, in `WriteTextSafe()`, write just `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lblState.Text = State));`. Same for the other Control -- Assuming a Thread is needed here. As it is now, it's not. You're using it to simply invoke back the UI Thread. Do you have some more complex procedure there?

Comment: That approach isn't updating the labels for the majority of calls (I only see a few updates). One of the first calls I make is to WriteTextSafe and so I'd expect to at a minimum see an update to that label.

Why do you write assuming a thread is needed for the other control?

I did try another approach of using a BackgroundWorker event handler, but for some reason that only succeeds sometimes. If I click on a button to trigger it. So everything so far is not consistently succeeding.

Comment: That code isn't assuming anything. You can call `BeginInvoke()` from any Thread, either the UI Thread or a background Thread or a Task that executes in a ThreadPool Thread. If you don't *see updates*, that probably depends on how / when / where you call the method that is supposed to update the U (I assume you have removed all `InvokeRequired` checks, not needed). You didn't show how this code is actually used or explained why you use a Thead for this

Comment: I started using a thread through some long meandering experimentation - no good reason. I'm fine not using a thread. What I'm doing to call it is simple: a button triggers a call to private async void DoStuff() which processes some data. At the start of it I added BeginInvoke (now to troubleshoot, I removed all else). So it's boiled down to a button triggering BeginInvoke. But no matter how many times I trigger it there's no change in the textbox. I did get backgrounder to work consistently (by adding thread sleep) but I'd rather use this approach. Any ideas of what I can try to troubleshoot?

Comment: If you have an async method, which returns `Task`, not `void`, you just make the `Click` handler of this Button `async` and `await DoStuff()`. No need to invoke anything, since you're still in the UI Thread in `DoStuff()`. If you `await Task.Run(()=> DoStuff())` instead, that method executes in a ThreadPool Thread, so you need `BeginInvoke()` -- As you may have noticed, you have to await the method calls. There's no possible way, in any case, that a Control is not updated, unless there's something inherently wrong with the real code, code that you haven't shown

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I see I was overcomplicating things. Boiling it down to updating the labels in UI thread and using await works. If you want to add as answer, I'll mark it.